# How do i share authentication token from facebook API between android and Drupal?

Tags: android, facebook, drupal-7, facebook-sdk-3.14.x

I am creating a native android application with Drupal at the backend. I also require the user to be able to login directly through facebook (using facebook android SDK). The authenticated users have special permissions to access certain nodes through ACL.

I am able to connect to FB and authenticate the user which returns a token for any future communication with facebook.

Now I need to use the same authentication token to tell Drupal that it's a valid user and the required permissions are granted. I am confused on how to achieve this.

Will appreciate if someone can help.